# Java, Selenium and getXpathCount

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

I am using Java to modify Selenium RC test cases.

```
package com.example.tests;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TestCase extends SeleneseTestCase {        

    @Test
    public void testLogin() throws Exception {

        selenium.windowMaximize();
        selenium.open("/en/QuoteGenerator.aspx");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        int r = selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='tblDetail']/tbody/tr[.]/td[1]");
        r = r - 2;
}
```

Eclipse is highlighting this part (`selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='tblDetail']/tbody/tr[.]/td[1]");`) and telling me the following error: `"Type mismatch: cannot convert from Number to int".`

I've tried using float, long, short, but all were in vain. How do I assign this number to a variable in this case. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Number result = selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@id='tblDetail']/tbody/tr[.]/td[1]");

int r = result.intValue();
```